# openpyxl - Ability to remove border from charts?

Tags: python, python-2.7, charts, openpyxl

Using openpyxl, the charts inserted into my worksheet have a border on them.  Is there any way to set the style of the chart (pie/bar) to either via the styles.Style/styles.borders module to have no border, or at least a thin white border so that they would print borderless?

The only options I see on the object is `.style = <int>` which doesn't seem to actually affect the design of the final graphic.

Answer (score 1):

You can set chat graphical_properties, the code is

```
chart.graphical_properties = GraphicalProperties(ln=LineProperties(noFill=True))
```

This will apply the line style to chartSpace.
Before you do this, you should modifiy the source code of `openpyxl lib`, the file is

```
Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\_chart.py
    #cs = ChartSpace(chart=container)
    cs = ChartSpace(chart=container, spPr=self.graphical_properties)
```

It works well.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't easy but should be possible. You will need to work through the XML source of a suitably formatted sample chart and see which particular variables need setting or changing. openpyxl implements the complete chart API but this unfortunately very complicated.

Comment: Ok, that gives me a location to start.  I'll leave this open for now in case someone else has a contribution and will report back what I find for future reference.

Comment: I think you might want to move any discussion over to the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

- Openpyxl stays close to the Office xml specification in respect to property names. It also provides alternative property names to make the code easier to read and I prefer to use those alternative names.
- By default a lot of the properties are None and you first need to initialize them with a proper class instance.

Here is an example function to hide the border:

```
from openpyxl.chart.shapes import GraphicalProperties

def hide_border(chart):
    if chart.graphical_properties is None:
        chart.graphical_properties = GraphicalProperties()
    line = chart.graphical_properties.line
    line.noFill = True
```

Also see:

- https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/charts/graphical.html
- https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/charts/introduction.html#styling-charts