# How to set up the Graphical Properties of Chart Area using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, charts, openpyxl

I would like to change the background color of Chart_area as well as remove all borders. Regarding the background color, I have tried the solution suggested: [How to set Background Color of Plot Area of Chart using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329669/how-to-set-background-color-of-plot-area-of-chart-using-openpyxl) but this solution doesn't work for any charts i.e. BarChart, AreaChart, LineChart, ScatterChart, RadarChart etc... I tried two openpyxl versions: 2.4.7, 2.4.9. without success.

```
# setup the chart
chart = LineChart()
# test to remove border line 
*****************************************************
chart.graphical_properties = 
GraphicalProperties(ln=LineProperties(noFill=True))
chart.height = 9
chart.width = 13.4
props = GraphicalProperties(solidFill="f2f2f2")

# setup and append the first series
list_names = ['Fund', 'Market', 'Benchmark']
data = Reference(ws2, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=n + 1, max_row=p + 
1)

chart.x_axis.number_format = 'mmm yy'
chart.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "months"
chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
dates = Reference(ws2, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=1, max_row=1 + p)
chart.set_categories(dates)
# Style the lines
chart.series[0].graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "7E3F00"
chart.series[1].graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "45788C"
chart.series[2].graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "8BADD9"
chart.plot_area.graphicalProperties = props
# test to change background color 
*****************************************************
chart.graphical_properties = props
ws1.add_chart(chart, "B14")
```

I also tried to remove the borders of chart_area. I found this post: [openpyxl - Ability to remove border from charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988384/openpyxl-ability-to-remove-border-from-charts). But I don't understand how do I handle to modify the library. I am a bit surprised that there is no simpler way.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is difficult because the underlying XML is 7, 8, 9 layers deep :-( openpyxl tries to simplify this where possible and doesn't expose everything but changes can be discussed on the mailing list.

Comment: Hi Charlie, thank you for your reply. Could you please just give me some guidance?

Answer (score 5):

This process may be helpful guidance to find an answer.

1. Open a new excel spreadsheet and create a chart of interest with
   default settings. Save this with filename
   "default-chart-saved-by-excel.xlsx".
2. Now modify the chart by changing the background color to purple (hex
   code 'AA00AA'). Save this with filename
   "redBG-chart-saved-by-excel.xlsx" and close excel.
3. Open the default excel file using a zip program (7zip or similar)
   and extract the xl > charts > chart1.xml file to your working
   folder. Rename it to "default-chart-saved-by-excel.xml" Repeat for
   the "redBG" case.
4. Open both of the xml files with an XML editor of choice (some web
   browsers work well) and look for the chunk of xml code that has
   changed by searching for the purple hex code 'AA00AA' That chunk is what you want openpyxl to target.