# How to set dash style to majorGridlines with openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Python 3.7, Openpyxl 2.5.12, O.S. Windows 7.

I would like to get majorGridlines with dot style. Is it possible to get this with openpyxl?

I have checked `openpyxl.drawing.line.LineProperties` class and I have seen there is an option called `prstDash = "dot"`. I have managed to get dash and dot styles with different series of a ScatterChart() like:

```
serie.graphicalProperties.line.dashStyle = "sysDot"
```

However, I am not able to give this property to majorGridLines. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to create a sample file with the styling you need and compare it with one created or processed by openpyxl. openpyxl implements the OOXML pretty closely so it should be possible to work out how what you need.

Comment: Hi Charlie, thank you for your answer. But to be honest, I am pretty newbie and I do not really understand what you say. Could you, please, specify it a little bit more?

Comment: All Office files are essentially a collection of XML files in a zip archive. The OOXML specification documents them all an generally explains how they work. So, if you unzip an XLSX with a chart you like and look at the `xl/charts/chart1.xml` (assuming there is only one chart) and compare it with one created by openpyxl then you should be able to see the additional settings and hopefully work out  what you need to change. Further discussion would be best on the mailing list.

Comment: Hi Charlie. Thank you for your explanation. Now, it is much more clear. I found this too (I think it is basically the same as you said): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305158/how-to-set-up-the-graphical-properties-of-chart-area-using-openpyxl).

Comment: Great. If you do work this out, would you consider adding it to the documentation?

Comment: The openpyxl documentation. We're always open to useful improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Update : 2022
Openpyxl 3.0.10, Python 3.8.3

```
#required modules to import
   import openpyxl
   from openpyxl.chart.shapes import GraphicalProperties
   from openpyxl.drawing.line import LineProperties
   from openpyxl.chart.axis import ChartLines

   #Add dash style to majorgridlines or minorgridlines
   chart = ScatterChart()
   chart.y_axis.majorGridlines= 
                ChartLines(spPr=GraphicalProperties(ln=LineProperties(prstDash 
                                                                  = 'dash'))))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.